# How to find out what component or extension of chrome is making a request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

I use Malwarebytes and recently it's made a popup once or twice that an attempt by `chrome.exe` to connect to a site called `catbox.moe` was blocked.

A quick google search lead me here: https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/198384-filescatboxmoe-66150188176/

And it appears to be that the site got infected with malware at some point in the past.

But my concern is: which part of chrome is doing this? Is it an extension? Some page I visited that loads it in the background?

In all likelihood, it's probably a page but if there's a possibility that one of the extensions is doing it, I'd like to be able to find out. What if some extension added something that uploads screenshots every so often without my knowledge? How would I even know?

Answer (score 1):

I own catbox.moe.

Catbox is a simple file sharing website, which people commonly use to embed a lot of things into webpages (images, videos, css, js, etc). What you're seeing is Malwarebytes blocking a request to Catbox from embedded content. I won't get into my opinion of the false positive. The only extension (that I know of) that has XHR permissions to Catbox is [Catbox's own web extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/catbox-uploader/onjcjibkpfjeoncglaobbjllfdhpcpeb).

Otherwise, you can look at individual permissions by going to chrome://extensions/ and clicking details under each extension.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I've looked at this and the details don't give much explicit reference to websites they'll be using. Only the Reddit Enhancement Suite does so and catbox.moe is not included in their listed websites. Other extensions simply mention they require permission to send things over the internet. Most likely some page I visited had some embedded content it tried to fetch. But there's no real way of being sure.